# Changing paths to fix Mac OSX:` -bash: jupyter: command not found`?

Tags: python, macos, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

This question has been covered previously on SO, but the recommended fixes didn't work.

I have installed Jupyter both with `pip install jupyter --upgrade` and macports `port install py34-jupyter` but I cannot access the command `jupyter` via the command line.

When executing `pip install jupyter`, the message is:

```
Requirement already satisfied: jupyter in /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages
```

This is also where pip is located. I have also tried

```
pip uninstall notebook
pip install notebook --upgrade
```

but this didn't work.

Inside `/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages`, I see:

```
jupyter-1.0.0-py3.4.egg-info
jupyter-1.0.0.dist-info
jupyter.py
jupyter_client
jupyter_client-4.4.0-py3.4.egg-info
jupyter_client-4.4.0.dist-info
jupyter_console
jupyter_console-5.0.0-py3.4.egg-info
jupyter_console-5.0.0.dist-info
jupyter_core
jupyter_core-4.2.0.dist-info
jupyter_core-4.2.1-py3.4.egg-info
```

I thought perhaps it was possible that the command `jupyter` does not have the correct path to the executable necessary, but this doesn't appear to be the case.

How can I have access to `jupyter notebook`?

Comment: After installing jupyter, has your python cli changed? It's supposed to use IPyhton after that... It will change from 

>>> command

to

In [1]: command

This would confirm if  IPython is being accessed when instantiating jupyter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using python on mac, I would strongly recommend using a virtualenv and installing all your dependencies using that. Had issues with installing and using several libraries.

```
pip install virtualenv virtualenvwrapper
# Create a backup of your .bash_profile
cp ~/.bash_profile ~/.bash_profile-org

# Be careful with this command
printf '\n%s\n%s\n%s' '# virtualenv' 'export WORKON_HOME=~/virtualenvs' \
'source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh' >> ~/.bash_profile

source ~/.bash_profile

mkdir -p $WORKON_HOME

mkvirtualenv your_virtual_env
```

This creates the virtual environment

```
deactivate
```

When you are out of virtual env, you can uninstall jupyter from your machine using `pip uninstall jupyter`

```
workon your_virtual_env
pip install jupyter
```